# Not able to update document in mongodb from node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am developing an online course application and I am trying to add new video lectures for a particular course, once the course is created. Once a course is created, after that, if we try to add new course then it sends update request, even if I am adding new video lectures, which is not present so far in the MongoDB. Here is my mongoose schema. File Name:- course.server.model.js.

```
    'use strict';
 /**
  * Module dependencies
  */
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 /**
  * Course Schema
  */
 var CourseSchema = new Schema({
     created: {
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now
     },
     title: {
         type: String,
         default: '',
         trim: true,
         required: 'Title cannot be blank'
     },
     content: {
         type: String,
         default: '',
         trim: true
     },
     // courseLecture: [String],
     courseLecture: [{
         lecture_title: {
             type: String
         },
         //  week_number: { type: Number },
         lecture_video: [String],
         pdf_files: [String]
         // lecture_video: [{ videoUrl: String }]
     }],
     /*
     courseLecture: {
     type: String,
     default: '',
     trim: true
     },*/
     user: {
         type: Schema.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User'
     }
 });

 mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);
```

Here is my node.js controller which updates the course. File Name:- courses.server.controller.js

```
   'use strict';

 /**
  * Module dependencies
  */
 var path = require('path'),
     mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     Course = mongoose.model('Course'),
     errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller'));

 /**
  * Create an course
  */
 exports.create = function(req, res) {
     var course = new Course(req.body);
     course.user = req.user;

     course.save(function(err) {
         if (err) {
             return res.status(422).send({
                 message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
             });
         } else {
             res.json(course);
         }
     });
 };

 /**
  * Show the current course
  */
 exports.read = function(req, res) {
     // convert mongoose document to JSON
     var course = req.course ? req.course.toJSON() : {};

     // Add a custom field to the Course, for determining if the current User is the "owner".
     // NOTE: This field is NOT persisted to the database, since it doesn't exist in the Course model.
     course.isCurrentUserOwner = !!(req.user && course.user && course.user._id.toString() === req.user._id.toString());

     console.log('course value is: ' + course);
     console.log('video lecture embed value is: ' + course.courseLecture.lecture_video);

     res.json(course);
 };

 /**
  * Update an course
  */
 exports.update = function(req, res) {
     var course = req.course;

     course.title = req.body.title;
     course.content = req.body.content;
     course.courseLecture.lecture_video = req.body.courseLecture.lecture_video;
     course.courseLecture.lecture_title = req.body.courseLecture.lecture_title;
     course.courseLecture.pdf_files = req.body.courseLecture.pdf_files;
     console.log('course lecture video url is: ' + req.body.courseLecture.lecture_video);
     course.save(function(err) {
         if (err) {
             return res.status(422).send({
                 message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
             });
         } else {
             res.json(course);
         }
     });
 };

 /**
  * Delete an course
  */
 exports.delete = function(req, res) {
     var course = req.course;

     course.remove(function(err) {
         if (err) {
             return res.status(422).send({
                 message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
             });
         } else {
             res.json(course);
         }
     });
 };

 /**
  * List of Courses
  */
 exports.list = function(req, res) {
     Course.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, courses) {
         if (err) {
             return res.status(422).send({
                 message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
             });
         } else {
             res.json(courses);
         }
     });
 };

 /**
  * Course middleware
  */
 exports.courseByID = function(req, res, next, id) {

     if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
         return res.status(400).send({
             message: 'Course is invalid'
         });
     }

     Course.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, course) {
         if (err) {
             return next(err);
         } else if (!course) {
             return res.status(404).send({
                 message: 'No course with that identifier has been found'
             });
         }
         req.course = course;
         next();
     });
 };
```

Interestingly I am able to update two fields i.e. title and content, however, whatever is there inside the courseLecture array, that I'm not able to update or make new save. 
Please let me know, where I am going wrong here.

TO add more clarity about my frontend work, I'm adding my angular controller and HTML file code. 
Angular controller. File name :- course.client.controller.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('courses.admin')
.controller('CoursesAdminController', CoursesAdminController);

CoursesAdminController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$window', 'courseResolve', 'Authentication', 'Notification'];

function CoursesAdminController($scope, $state, $window, course, Authentication, Notification) {
var vm = this;

vm.course = course;
vm.authentication = Authentication;
vm.form = {};
vm.remove = remove;
vm.save = save;
vm.ShowHide = ShowHide;
vm.addNewChoice = addNewChoice;

$scope.IsVisible = false;
function ShowHide() {
  // If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
  $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
}

function addNewChoice() {
  $scope.vm.course.courseLecture.push('');
}

// Remove existing Course
function remove() {
  if ($window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
    vm.course.$remove(function() {
      $state.go('admin.courses.list');
      Notification.success({ message: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Course deleted successfully!' });
    });
  }
}

// Save Course
function save(isValid) {
  if (!isValid) {
    $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'vm.form.courseForm');
    return false;
  }

  // Create a new course, or update the current instance
  vm.course.createOrUpdate()
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(errorCallback);

  function successCallback(res) {
    $state.go('admin.courses.list'); // should we send the User to the list or the updated Course's view?
    Notification.success({ message: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Course saved successfully!' });
  }

  function errorCallback(res) {
    Notification.error({ message: res.data.message, title: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Course save error!' });
  }
}
}
}());
```

My HTML file. File Name:- form-course.client.view.html

```
<section>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>{{vm.course._id ? 'Edit Course' : 'New Course'}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
  <a ng-show="vm.course._id" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.remove()">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <form name="vm.form.courseForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="vm.save(vm.form.courseForm.$valid)" novalidate>
     <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" show-errors>
           <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
           <input name="title" type="text" ng-model="vm.course.title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
           <div ng-messages="vm.form.courseForm.title.$error" role="alert">
              <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Course title is required.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label" for="content">Content</label>
           <textarea name="content" data-ng-model="vm.course.content" id="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <!--  <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-ui-sref="admin.courses.createLecture">  -->
        <div>
           <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="vm.ShowHide()">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
           </a><br>
           <div ng-show="IsVisible">
              <div class="page-header">
                 <h1>{{vm.course._id ? 'Edit Lecture' : 'New Lecture'}}</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="pull-right">
                 <a ng-show="vm.course._id" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.remove()">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                 </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
  <form name="vm.form.courseForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="vm.save(vm.form.courseForm.$valid)" novalidate>
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="field in vm.course.courseLecture track by $index">
  <div class="form-group" show-errors>
  <label class="control-label" for="LectureTitle">Lecture Title</label>
  <input name="courseLecture" type="text" ng-model="vm.course.courseLecture.lecture_title[$index]" id="LectureTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Lecture Title" required autofocus>
  <div ng-messages="vm.form.courseForm.title.$error" role="alert">
  <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Lecture name is required.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="courseLecture">Add Lecture video url here</label>
  <input name="courseLecture" type="text" ng-model="vm.course.courseLecture.lecture_video[$index]" id="courseLecture" class="form-control" placeholder="course Lecture">
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.addNewChoice()" value="Add another URL">
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{vm.course._id ? 'Update' : 'Create'}}</button>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you post the dump of the course object before and after you populate it with new values from `req.body`?

Comment: if I do console.log of "req.body.courseLecture.lecture_video", then I get undefined. @nainy

Comment: Well, it probably means that your data isn't getting to the model. Mongo, if I recall correctly, interprets all `undefined` values as ignorable, so your data isn't being erased but isn't updated, either. 

Try to comment out the part where you populate your model from req.body, hardcode something different to what's in your database and save it, then look whether the model had changed in mongo.

Comment: Another thing it could mean is that Mongo Schema's internal setter discards the data that isn't of the type you specified. Are you sure you are passing an array of strings as you've specified?

Comment: Yes I'm passing array of string @nainy

Comment: I'd still advise you dump your `req.body.courseLecture` and `course.courseLecture` before you do any assignment and see whether there is data in both. I strongly suspect the absence of data in the body is the cause.

Comment: Oh, wait. I've looked closer at your Schema. You've defined the `courseLecture` as an Array of Objects, but from your code it seems that you've meant to define it as a nested object. That's what is most likely the problem.

Comment: What should I do then to fix it @nainy

Answer (score 0):

```
 exports.update = function(req, res) {
 var course = req.course;
```

Your req.course is not a mongodb object. you can use findOneAndUpdate method of mongoose
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Interestingly I am able to update two fields i.e. title and content, however whatever is there inside the courseLecture array, that i'm not able to update or make new save.

Answer (score 0):

If your data currently looks like:

```
{
   courseLecture: {
     lecture_title: 'Test',
     lecture_video: ['vid1', 'vid2'],
     pdf_files: ['pdf1', 'pdf2']
   }
}
```

I think what you need to do is change this bit:

```
 courseLecture: [{
     lecture_title: {
         type: String
     },
     //  week_number: { type: Number },
     lecture_video: [String],
     pdf_files: [String]
     // lecture_video: [{ videoUrl: String }]
 }]
```

to this:

```
 courseLecture: {
     lecture_title: {
         type: String
     },
     lecture_video: {type: [String] },
     pdf_files: {type: [String] }
 }
```

You've initially defined the Schema as having an array of objects in the 'courseLecture' field, so either the validation doesn't pass during save, or the Schema doesn't even perform the `set` operation.

Comment: If I do this, then it breaks my frontend code and then it fails. @nainy

Comment: Can you post an example of the data you pass to your model in the body? I'm trying to infer from your code, but maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: courseLecture: {
    lecture_title: { "test title"},
    lecture_video: ["test_video"],
    pdf_files: ["testpdf"]
  }                              @nainy

Comment: `lecture_title: { "test title"}` is invalid syntax, but otherwise it seems like I've got your actual Schema right.

Comment: I've updated the answer slightly, see if that helps.

Comment: in my browser i'm getting, .. "Failed to load resource: The server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) @nainy